# Block bingbot from crawling my site

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .htaccess, bots, robots.txt, bing

I would like t completely block bing from crawling my site for now (its attacking my site at an alarming rate (500GB of data a month).

I have 1000 sub domains added to bing webmaster tools so i cant go and set each one's crawl rate.
I have tried blocking it using robots.txt but its not working
here is my robots.txt

```
# robots.txt 
User-agent: *
Disallow:
Disallow: *.axd
Disallow: /cgi-bin/
Disallow: /member
Disallow: bingbot
User-agent: ia_archiver
Disallow: /
```

Comment: I also found bingbot doing this on many.. many websites I manage. Completely ignores general "*" rules and any Crawl-delays.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**This WILL definitely affect your SEO/search ranking and will cause pages to drop from the index so please use with care**

You can block requests based on the user-agent string if you have the iis rewrite module installed (if not go [here](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite))

And then add a rule to your webconfig like this:

```
<system.webServer>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Request Blocking Rule" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="msnbot|BingBot" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="CustomResponse" statusCode="403" statusReason="Forbidden: Access is denied." statusDescription="You do not have permission to view this page." />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</system.webServer>
```

This will return a 403 if the bot hits your site.

**UPDATE**

Looking at your robots.txt i think it should be:

```
# robots.txt 
User-agent: *
Disallow:
Disallow: *.axd
Disallow: /cgi-bin/
Disallow: /member
User-agent: bingbot
Disallow: /
User-agent: ia_archiver
Disallow: /
```

Comment: Thank you that seem to work.. at least from bing webmaster toolbox verification.

Comment: No problem - I've also added to my answer what I think your robots file should be (the first disallow should be "/" rather than blank.) Bots do take time to pick up changes in robots.txt files though, even if you submit them via webmaster tools.

Comment: The updated robot will ban all crawlers i think. right now I am trying to stop just bing from crawling until I figure out why its attacking it so much.

Comment: The web.config solution works in Framework 2.0 deploy in IIS 6 Windows 2003 Server?

Answer (score 4):

Your robots.txt is not correct:

- You need line breaks between records (a record starts with one or more `User-agent` lines).
- `Disallow: bingbot` disallows crawling of URLs whose paths start with "bingbot" (i.e., `http://example.com/bingbot`), which is probably not what you want.
- Not an error, but `Disallow:` is not needed (as it’s the default anyway).

So you probably want to use:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: *.axd
Disallow: /cgi-bin/
Disallow: /member

User-agent: bingbot
User-agent: ia_archiver
Disallow: /
```

This disallows crawling of anything for "bingbot" and "ia_archiver". All other bots are allowed to crawl everything except URLs whose paths start with `/member`, `/cgi-bin/`, or `*.axd`.

Note that `*.axd` will be interpreted literally by bots following the original robots.txt specification (so they will not crawl `http://example.com/*.axd`, but they will crawl `http://example.com/foo.axd`). However, many bots extend the spec and interpret the `*` as some kind of wildcard.